# Best SIM option for UK and Italy?

Tags: uk, cellphones, italy

My partner is Italian and we live in the UK. We frequently travel to Italy. We'd like to have a phone that we can use to call Italy affordably from the UK, and use in Italy to contact both Italian number and UK numbers.

Is there a UK or Italian (or international) SIM or deal that we could take advantage of for this? Is the best idea to just have two and take good care of them?

Comment: Two SIMs. Roaming charges are insane.

Comment: @JoErNanO While most are, those within the EU are capped and are generally pretty reasonable

Answer (score 4):

Option #1: [Three using their Feel At Home](http://www.three.co.uk/Discover/Phones/Feel_At_Home) special deal available on all their price plans. As both the UK and Italy are covered, with a UK sim, you can use your bundles of minutes / texts / data for no additional charge when in Italy (amongst [other countries](http://www.three.co.uk/Discover/Phones/Feel_At_Home)).

- UK calling UK = normal prices / free with bundle
- Italy calling UK = free with bundle / add-on
- Italy calling Italy = free with bundle / add-on
- UK calling Italy = [46p/minute](http://www.three.co.uk/Support/Roaming_and_international/Calling_and_texting_abroad_from_the_UK/__destination_details/1214306357967) without an add-on

Option #2: [EE 4GEE](http://explore.ee.co.uk/4gee-extra-plans-roaming-benefits) which comes with free texts and calls roaming anywhere in the EU, but isn't available on pay-as-you-go:

- UK calling UK - free with bundle
- Italy calling UK - free
- Italy calling Italy - free
- Italy calling anywhere else in Europe - free
- UK calling Italy - [5p/minute landlines, 20p/minute mobiles](http://ee.co.uk/help/add-ons-benefits-and-plans/call-or-going-abroad/international-calling-abroad/calling-abroad-from-the-uk)

Option #3 - Get any sim from any non-UK non-Italy EU country, and pay the quite low EU-capped roaming rates everywhere! With the EU caps it's currently a [maximum of €0.05/minute above your domestic rates](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/roaming-tariffs), so with a cheap package from elsewhere in the EU roaming can be cheap!

Comment: Can't wait for June 2017.

Comment: I can vouch for 3 UK pay as you go, buying add-ons for the voice minutes and data you'll use in Italy.  I've had the same sim for 8 years, it doesn't expire from extended disuse. The only problem may be topping up if you run short when you are outside the UK and you don't have a UK credit/debit card (I have one).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sign contracts you can get free sims from Lykamobile or Lybara and use them as Pay As You Go.

Calls cost from 5-7p. roaming also cheap.

http://www.lebara.co.uk/

http://www.lycamobile.co.uk/en/italy

http://www.lycamobile.it/it/